# Showing a small subset of font choices in Powerpoint/Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

Is it possible to make only a small subset of fonts show up in the long list of Powerpoint/Word fonts, so that I do not have to scroll trough millions of fonts I never use to find the one(s) I need? In my 20+ years of using Powerpoint for teaching and research presentations, I've only used 4 fonts -- Arial, TNR, Cambria Math, and Symbol for Greek letters. I do use my own template that defaults to Arial, but when someone sends me their own ppt (which used the default template), I have to seek out my 3 simple fonts among the millions of useless ones.

Thank you all in advance!

P.S.  Despite the use of my default ppt template, MS finds ways to sneak their Calibri in, e.g. via a rarely used shape which I haven't defaulted to Arial, or when I cut and paste as plain text -- magically it all becomes Calibri.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in PowerPoint, Word, etc to restrict the list of fonts you see; the font list pretty much reflects the fonts installed in Windows or Mac (with a few exceptions, e.g. for fonts that the applications don't support).

You haven't mentioned whether you use Mac or Windows Office.  In Windows, at least, if you don't want to scroll all the way down the font list, you can just type the name of the font you want into the font box on the ribbon/Home tab. Be careful, though ... PPT will accept any reasonable or idiotic thing you type. If you want to torment a colleague, select some text and type FIND ME IF YOU CAN into the font name text box. PPT will happily accept this. ;-)

Another approach, at least on Windows, would be to use a font manager program. Most of them let you create sets of fonts for specific tasks. If you created one with just the fonts you need for presentations, and call it into action, PPT's font list should reflect your choice and display just the fonts included in the set.

As to Calibri sneaking in, each presentation/template can have default text/formatting for shapes and text boxes. Create a text box, format it as desired, then right click and choose Set As Default. Same applies to shapes.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. Indeed, I forgot to mention that this is W10 at the moment and office 365. I guess I cannot just uninstall all fonts except 5 :) b.c. this might screw up the rest of the applications. "Set as default" is what I did for my custom template, but there are dozens, if not hundreds, of different shapes. I defaulted a few, but every now and then I used one I've not used before (e.g. a 32-point star!) and here goes Calibri again. I wish there was a way to weed out Calibri and default fonts in ALL shapes to the one I want, not 1 shape at a time. Nice one on the font name, I will try!!

Comment: Installing them all would cause problems and in fact won't even be possible in some cases; Windows squirrels away hidden copies of the fonts it comes with and uses them if they're not in the usual Fonts folder. My guess re Calibri: you're getting it because it's the default heading/body font set in the theme you're using. Go View | Slide Master and use the Fonts dropdown in the Background group to select another font theme. See if that changes things.  It should.

Comment: Thank you, Steve! I will do what you suggested re: another font theme

Comment: One newish feature I want to suggest: replace fonts. It's not a permanent solution, but you can instances change all instances of one font with another one

Comment: Good suggestion, @JackStoneS. Replace Fonts doesn't work perfectly (may not replace fonts in charts, won't replace them in graphics/ole objects, won't replace double-byte or unicode fonts with singlebyte fonts) but it's a good place to start. It's not actually all that new, btw. I have a hunch it goes as far back as PPT '97.